# Alternatives for single or double quotes?

Tags: php, variables, conventions

This example:

```
$var = '<?php
    $_SESSION["a"] = 1;
    echo "<script>console.log($_SESSION["a"]);</script>";
?>'
```

returns an error because it thinks the quotes should stop before the a. If I used single quotes, the $var would instead stop in the middle. Is there another alternative that could be used to wrap the 'a' in $_SESSION["a"] around without causing errors?

Comment: Does it answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Why are you trying to put PHP code inside a PHP variable?

Comment: `$foo = "hello \"bar\" world";`.

Comment: Yes, as Cid wrote, with a backslash you can [escape a quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), making it a literal quote.

Comment: @Syscall so basically you can wrap the code around <<<EOT and EOT, so $_SESSION[<<<EOT a EOT]?

Comment: @ADyson well, I want to output it to a file

Comment: @Cid doesn't seem to work for single quotes

Comment: It works. You're not doing it right if you're getting errors when escaping quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is another simple way to fix your problem:

```
<?php
session_start();

function setSession($name, $data)
{
    $_SESSION["$name"] = $data;
}

$var = setSession("a", 1);
?>

<script> 
console.log(<?php echo $var ?>);
</script>
```